# Kafka topic creation using java api without zookeeper

Tags: java, apache-kafka

How to create kafka topic without zookeeper dependency for kafka 0.10.1.x using java? 
I have seen threads where topics were created but it used zookeeper, zk client etc. I want to do it using java only, no scala dependency as already kafka 0.10 is not using zookeeper.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to create Kafka topics without connecting to ZooKeeper.

While this feature is available in the broker from Kafka 0.10.1, the AdminClient (client code to use the broker feature) was only added in Kafka 0.11.

See `KafkaAdminClient.createTopics()`: http://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/KafkaAdminClient.html#createTopics-java.util.Collection-org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.CreateTopicsOptions-

Comment: yes, I was trying keeping the maven dependency on version 0.10 itself.  It is possible with higher versions.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The feature is available on the client side since 0.11.0.0 with the new Admin Client API that will replace the legacy ones overtime.
You can find a simple example on using it here : https://github.com/ppatierno/kafka-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/playground/CreateTopic.java

Comment: yes, I was trying keeping the maven dependency on version 0.10 itself. It is possible with higher versions.Thanks.